# How to Use Radio Buttons and Input in JavaScript Function with If/Then Statements

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on creating a simple increase/decrease percentage calculator using HTML and JavaScript. I honestly am not sure where my actual code is going wrong. It worked fine until I added an if/then statement in the JavaScript. Everything "appears" to be right, but the result is not printing to the screen at the tag ID I specify. I am new to JavaScript and HTML so this is just some learning for me. Thanks in advance!

```js
              function getPercentageChange() {
              var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
              var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

              if (button1.checked){
                var d_oldNumber = document.getElementById('originalnumber').value;
                var d_newNumber = document.getElementById('newnumber').value;
                var decreaseValue = d_oldNumber - d_newNumber;
                var decreaseresults = (decreaseValue / oldNumber) * 100;
                document.getElementById('percentageIncrease').innerHTML = descreaseresults + '%';
              } else if (button2.checked) {
                var i_oldNumber = document.getElementById('originalnumber').value;
                var i_newNumber = document.getElementById('newnumber').value;
                var increaseValue = i_oldNumber - i_newNumber;
                var increaseresults = (increaseValue / i_oldNumber) * 100;
                document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = increaseresults + '%';
              }
            }
```

```html
          Percentage Increase <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="1" id="button1"/><br>
          Percentage Decrease <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="2" id="button2"/><br>
          &nbsp;
          &nbsp;
          &nbsp;


          <p>Original Number:
            <input type="numeric" id="originalnumber" value=""><br>

             New Number:
            <input type="numeric" id="newnumber" value=""><br><br>
          </p>

           <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="getPercentageChange();">
           <div id = "percentage"></div>


            <p id="percentage"></p>
```

Comment: Looks like a typo `oldNumber` should be `d_oldNumber` in the `if` statement for `button1.checked`

Comment: Also there is no object with the id of percentageIncrease and there is a typo for decreaseresults. And IDs are meant to be unique so you can't reuse percentage id.

Comment: Yea that would do it lol Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This statement uses an undefined variable `oldNumber`. Perhaps change it to `d_oldNumber`?

```
            var decreaseresults = (decreaseValue / oldNumber) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply had some miss-spelled variables: d_oldNumber, oldNumber and the id oldNumber.

```js
function getPercentageChange() {
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

  if (button1.checked) {
    var d_oldNumber = document.getElementById('originalnumber').value;
    var d_newNumber = document.getElementById('newnumber').value;
    var decreaseValue = d_oldNumber - d_newNumber;
    var decreaseresults = (decreaseValue / d_oldNumber) * 100;
    document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = decreaseresults + '%';
  } else if (button2.checked) {
    var i_oldNumber = document.getElementById('originalnumber').value;
    var i_newNumber = document.getElementById('newnumber').value;
    var increaseValue = i_oldNumber - i_newNumber;
    var increaseresults = (increaseValue / i_oldNumber) * 100;
    document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = increaseresults + '%';
  }
}
```

```html
Percentage Increase <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="1" id="button1" /><br> Percentage Decrease <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="2" id="button2" /><br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


<p>Original Number:
  <input type="numeric" id="originalnumber" value=""><br> New Number:
  <input type="numeric" id="newnumber" value=""><br><br>
</p>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="getPercentageChange();">
<div id="percentage"></div>


<p id="percentage"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a few of your variables equate to the same result, you could simplify this function to save yourself mix-ups. There are a few instances where there were mis-spellings of variable names in your code

```js
function getPercentageChange() {
  var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
  var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

  var oldNumber = document.getElementById('originalnumber').value;
  var newNumber = document.getElementById('newnumber').value;
  var difference = oldNumber - newNumber;
  var results = (difference / oldNumber) * 100;


  if (button1.checked) {
    document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = results + '%';
  } else if (button2.checked) {
    document.getElementById('percentage').innerHTML = results + '%';
  }
}
```

```html
Percentage Increase <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="1" id="button1" /><br> Percentage Decrease <input type="radio" name="radionbutton" value="2" id="button2" /><br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;


<p>Original Number:
  <input type="numeric" id="originalnumber" value=""><br> New Number:
  <input type="numeric" id="newnumber" value=""><br><br>
</p>

<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="getPercentageChange();">
<div id="percentage"></div>


<p id="percentage"></p>
```

Hope this helps